# Ajax POST method not working in PHP, but GET is working

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, post

I am trying to send using Ajax a POST request to php.

If I use GET it works fine, but with POST the data I receive in php is empty.
I'm sending data as a json.

This is what the js code looks like:

```
$.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'php/GiveItBack.php',
            contentType: "json",
            data: {
                word: 'abc'
            },
            success: function (json) {
                alert(json);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert('ERROR: ' + errorThrown); }
        });
```

This is the php/GiveItBack.php file

```
<?php

$x = $_GET['word'];
echo 'Get: ' . $x;

$x = $_POST['word'];
echo '; Post: ' . $x;

$x = $_REQUEST['word'];
echo '; Request: ' . $x . ';';

?>
```

With this code, the message in the alert window looks like this:

> Get: ; Post: ; Request: ;

If I replace **type: 'POST'** in the js file with **type: 'GET'** this is the result I get in the alert window (as I was expecting to see):

> Get: abc; Post: ; Request: abc;

I can't see what I'm missing here.
Is something wrong in the code or is any special setting I need to do for this to work.

By the way I am using: **jquery-2.2.4.min** and php **v5.6** and XAMPP v3.2.2.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked your phpinfo?  Is POST activated?

Comment: This line **;enable_post_data_reading = Off** commented and by default is on. So I guess it's activated.

Comment: Try print instead of echo, not really sure why but I've had issues using echo in the past

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The content type was not correct, need to use `contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` OR `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`

```
   $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'php/GiveItBack.php',
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        data: {
            word: 'abc'
        },
        success: function (json) {
            alert(json);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert('ERROR: ' + errorThrown); }
    });
```

Comment: Why? Can you explain why it needs to be removed for POST?

Comment: Thank you. This worked. But what is the problem with using **contentType: "json"**?

Comment: @Horatiu Because `json` isn't a valid content type. This is like `enctype` in a form. I was hoping Dhara would actually provide an explanation for you. I think what you're after is `dataType`, which specifies the format of the return data.

Comment: set contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" , only json is invalid content type, for json - use 'Content-Type': 'application/json'

Comment: @Styphon yes content type was not correct, need to use contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" OR 'Content-Type': 'application/json'

Comment: @DharaParmar So add that to your answer, to be a good answer you shouldn't just give the solution, but explain what the OP did wrong and why it was wrong so they learn.

Answer (score 1):

> `contentType: "json",`

You content type is wrong here. If you want to receive it the way you are trying, you should use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

If you still want to stick within JSON, you will have to `json_decode` your PHP input:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json, TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax(
    {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'php/GiveItBack.php',
        data: {
            word: 'abc'
        },
        success: function (json) {
            alert(json);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert('ERROR: ' + errorThrown); }
    });
```

Comment: type is an alias for method...  So why should it work this way?  Could you please explain.

Comment: I tried to replace type with method... is not working.  Tried to use both method and type, still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `contentType: json` and you should be able to use the `$_POST` superblogal array. If you use `contentType: json` the object containing the parameters is converted into a string and sent over to the server. To get the string you will need to use

`file_get_contents('php://input');`

This happens because `$_POST` only contains data sent along with the following headers:

- application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- multipart/form-data-encoded

When you set `contentType: json`, jQuery adds the `application/json` header to the request which is not supported by `$_POST` so the JSON string is treated as raw input and therefore you need to use the `php://input` stream to retrieve it

Answer (score 0):

Ajax Data
Remove the `contentType: json`:

```
$.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'php/GiveItBack.php',

        data: {
            word: 'abc'
        },
        success: function (json) {
            alert(json);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert('ERROR: ' + errorThrown); }
    });
```

Comment: please check this[URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to raise your content quality up